# Find $\limsup_{n\to\infty} Y_n$ given the value of $\mathbb{E}(\limsup_{n\to\infty} Y_n)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I came across a question online which asks for $\limsup_{n\to\infty} Y_n$, given that $\mathbb{E}(\limsup_{n\to\infty} Y_n)=1$, where $\{Y_n\}$ is a sequence of independent r.v.s.

I cannot seem to figure this out. I have a feeling that the answer will be somewhat obvious, although I've tried many approaches, from Fatou's Lemma to Borel-Cantelli. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try with Kolmogorov 0-1 law

Comment: That did come to mind at one point, but how do I relate expectation to the zero-one law? Any event in the tail-sigma algebra is of probability zero or one, so how can we go from there? The definition of lim sup certainly resembles the tail algebra using unions as the variables, but not sure how to obtain a value of the lim sup from this...

Comment: Ignore my previous comment, I must have been half-awake. Anyway, try Lucio's hint to the probability $$ \mathbb{P}\left[ \limsup_{n\to\infty} Y_n \leq y \right], \qquad y \in \mathbb{R}$$ to see what can you conclude for the distribution of $\limsup_{n\to\infty} Y_n$.

Comment: It is a general fact that, if a random variable is measurable w.r.t. the tail sigma algebra of the $\{Y_n \}$, then it will be almost surely constant. The proof is essentially as in @SangchulLee comment. $\limsup Y_n$ is measurable w.r.t. the tail sigma algebra because it does not depend on any finite evaluations of the $Y_n$

Comment: Thanks Lucio and Sangchul, it's working out how expectations are involved that is confusing. If lim sup is sigma measurable, then it must be 0 or 1, so since the expected value is 1, the lim sup must be 1?

Comment: No, since it’s sigma measurable it will be almost surely constant, but a priori the constant could be any real number. But you’re right that the constant will have to coincide with the mean of limsup, so it must be 1.

Comment: Oh sorry, my mistake (the probability must be 0 or 1, not the variable!)